# Set default AWS Region from userdata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I have a cluster of nodes utilizing the same ami.

I would like to change the default region on startup to us-east-1

If this possible to pass in user data even if it is writing a config file in ~/.aws/

Comment: Why are you using credentials files on EC2 instances? Can you not use IAM roles (and instance profiles) to provide credentials to the instances?

Comment: could you please share code snippet and also share more details?  given link could be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User Data script runs as the `root` user, which has permission to change any files on the disk.

So, yes, you can put a command in the script that would edit `/users/ec2-user/.aws/config` (or whatever user directory you are using).